# Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks

Tags: react-native, npm, react-hooks, expo

I have run into this error in my code, and don't really know how to solve it, can anyone help me?

I get the following error message:

> ERROR Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by ScreenA. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Pressable } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { DancingScript_400Regular } from "@expo-google-fonts/dancing-script";
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

export default function ScreenA({ route }) {

    const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function prepare() {
            try {
                // Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
                await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

                // Pre-load fonts, make any API calls you need to do here
                await Font.loadAsync({ DancingScript_400Regular });

                // Artificially delay for two seconds to simulate a slow loading
                // experience. Please remove this if you copy and paste the code!
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
            } catch (e) {
                console.warn(e);
            } finally {
                // Tell the application to render
                setAppIsReady(true);
            }
        }

        prepare();
    }, []);

    const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
        if (appIsReady) {
            // This tells the splash screen to hide immediately! If we call this after
            // `setAppIsReady`, then we may see a blank screen while the app is
            // loading its initial state and rendering its first pixels. So instead,
            // we hide the splash screen once we know the root view has already
            // performed layout.
            await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        }
    }, [appIsReady]);

    if (!appIsReady) {
        return null;
    }

    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const onPressHandler = () => {
        // navigation.navigate('Screen_B', { itemName: 'Item from Screen A', itemID: 12 });
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.body} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>
                Screen A
            </Text>
            <Pressable
                onPress={onPressHandler}
                style={({ pressed }) => ({ backgroundColor: pressed ? '#ddd' : '#0f0' })}
            >
                <Text style={styles.text}>
                    Go To Screen B
                </Text>
            </Pressable>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{route.params?.Message}</Text>
        </View>
    )

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    body: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 40,
        margin: 10,
        fontFamily: 'DancingScript_400Regular'
    }
})
```

I have read the rules of hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

The output is correct, but i want to fix this error before i add more additions to the app

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `useNavigation` use [before early returns](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).

> Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns.

The key is you need to call all the hooks in the exact same order on every component lifecycle update, which means you can't use hooks with conditional operators or loop statements such as:

```js
if (customValue) useHook();

// or
for (let i = 0; i< customValue; i++) useHook();

// or
if (customValue) return;
useHook();
```

So moving  `const navigation = useNavigation();` before  `if (!appIsReady) {return null;}`, should solve your problem:

```js
export default function ScreenA({ route }) {

    const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    // ...
}
```